# Can't wrap my head around on how to solve Function problems :(

Tags: functions

Given $g(t)=3t^2-1$ and $h(t)=\frac{t}{4}+1$

find:

1. $h(t^2+1)$
2. $(g∘h)(t)$
3. $h^{-1}(t)$

Comment: $h(t^2)$ means take your formula for $h(t)$, everywhere you see $t$, replace it by $t^2$.

Comment: If you are willing to look again at your question and fix the errors ($t^2+...$), we can help you quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm still finding my way around here and the proper use of everything. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $g(x)$ represents some function, with input $x$. Remember, $x$ is just a placeholder for any general "thing". For example, when $g(t)=3t^2-1$, $t$ could mean anything. And when $g$ happens to anything, that thing gets squared, then multiplied by $3$, and then has $1$ subtracted from it. So:

$$g(4)=3(4^2)-1$$
$$g(a)=3(a^2)-1$$
$$g(\&)=3(\&^2)-1$$

The last one is weird, because the symbol $'\&'$ is not defined. But whatever it means, nothing changes about what $g$ does to it. Just like every other input, $\&$ gets squared, then multiplied by $3$, then has $1$ subtracted from it.

Then, $g(h(t))=3(h(t)^2)-1$

Is this helpful?

Try to write a few out. Do them one at a time, and ask questions as soon as you have them.

Comment: But the *thing* must be in the domain of the function, e.g. $g(\mathrm{cats})$ isn't defined.

Comment: @YiFan sure, but is that technical detail really needed when the person is just trying to understand the 'plug-in' aspect?